# Inject EJBs into a Seam Component

Tags: components, ejb-3.0, seam, lookup, code-injection

guys. I have a Seam project running on Tomcat 6.0.20 (webapp.war) and an EJB project running on JBoss 4.2.3 (ejbapp.ear).

I can access my EJBs in my Seam components using JNDI lookup [initialContext.lookup(...)].
I'd like to have them injected in my Seam components instead.

My Seam components ARE NOT EJBs, so I can't use @EJB annotation. I'd like to have something like this in my Tomcat (Web) app.

```
@Name("customerAction")
public class CustomerAction {

    @In // even with (autoCreate=true) or the EJB name if necessary
    private CustomerEJB customerEJB;

    ...
}
```

And this in the JBoss (EJB) app.

```
@Stateless(name="customerEJB")
public class CustomerEJBImpl implements CustomerEJB {
    ...
}

@Remote
public interface CustomerEJB {
    ...
}
```

In my components.xml I have the jndiPattern=ejbapp/@jndiPattern/remote specified just like I currently use to lookup the EJBs (ex: ejbapp/CustomerEJB/remote).

I'm probably missing something in my configuration to make this work.
PS: I'd like NOT HAVE to annotate my EJBs as @Name (Seam) components.

Any suggestions? Thanks in advance.

---

Thanks for your reply, but it didn't work.

When I declared the EJBs in components.xml, it did inject the object in my Action (Seam component), but as a POJO. I mean, the EntityManager and other EJB injections I had in the injected object didn't work.

I also tried to define the EJB as a Seam component, but, once they are in the webproject inside a JAR file, it didn't load automatically, and trying the scenario above, I got the same error.

Just an FYI, I also declared the Seam interceptor in ejb-jar.xml file.
I have no idea why this is happening, BTW I thought it would be quite a simple thing for Seam to handle.

Anyway..., any other suggestions, guys?

Answer (score 0):

Define your EJB as Seam components in your components.xml